# why does cytoscape nodes need two taps instead of one to fire click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, cytoscape.js

I am building a network view using cytoscape.js and need to catch tap event on nodes. The event fires very well on edges and background but needs two taps to get fired on nodes. I used both 'click' and 'tap' event like below but still can't fire the event on first tap. Any clues !?

```
cy.on('tap',function(e){
  // console.log(e)
  console.log('click detected ', e)
})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You always need to unbind the event before you bind it, otherwise you may have some trouble with some events firing twiche.

Also, you should specify, which elements you want to bind the event on, so either 'node', 'edge' or everything. That way your event is more accurate.

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "60px",
        "border-color": "black",
        "border-opacity": "1",
        "border-width": "10px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "$node > node",
      css: {
        "padding-top": "10px",
        "padding-left": "10px",
        "padding-bottom": "10px",
        "padding-right": "10px",
        "text-valign": "top",
        "text-halign": "center",
        "background-color": "#bbb"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge[label]",
      css: {
        label: "data(label)",
        "text-rotation": "autorotate",
        "text-margin-x": "0px",
        "text-margin-y": "0px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ":selected",
      css: {
        "background-color": "black",
        "line-color": "black",
        "target-arrow-color": "black",
        "source-arrow-color": "black"
      }
    }
  ],
  layout: {
    name: "circle"
  }
}));

var info = [{
    name: "Peter",
    next_op_name: "Claire"
  },
  {
    name: "Claire",
    next_op_name: "Mike"
  },
  {
    name: "Mike",
    next_op_name: "Rosa"
  },
  {
    name: "Rosa",
    next_op_name: "Peter"
  }
];

cy.ready(function() {
  var array = [];
  // iterate over info once
  for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
    array.push({
      group: "nodes",
      data: {
        id: info[i].name, // id is name!!!
        label: info[i].name
      }
    });
    array.push({
      group: "edges",
      data: {
        id: "e" + i,
        source: info[i].name,
        target: info[i].next_op_name,
        label: "e" + i
      }
    });
  }
  cy.add(array);
  cy.layout({
    name: "circle"
  }).run();
});

// Here is the important part
cy.unbind("tap"); // unbind event to prevent possible mishaps with firing too many events
cy.bind("tap", function(evt) { // bind with .bind() (synonym to .on() but more intuitive
  console.log(evt.target);
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <!-- qtip imports -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/2.7.0/cytoscape-qtip.js"></script>

  <!-- dagre imports -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank's a lot! But still need to click twice to fire tap event on nodes. I think it is du to the internal working of cytoscape. the first click triggers the start fucntion of edgehandler that allows to draw the edge.

Comment: Nah, the code works with one click for me, are you sure that you have cytoscape and all parts of the code (the unbind etc) in your file?

Comment: I use cytoscape with vue.js. I imported cytoscape with npm, I suppose everything is in there. I write the tap function inside the mounted and tried to do the bind unbind, but did'nt change anything !!

Comment: Well can you provide a reproducable example (via snippet), otherwise it's a needle in a haystack :D

Comment: Events bubble up, just like in the DOM.  On a tap of a node, the handler is called once for the node and once bubbled up for the core.  Use a selector like @StephanT. suggested, or add listeners directly to particular nodes.